# An airplane makes a 990 km flight with a tailwind and returns, flying into the same wind.

Tags: quadratics

An airplane makes a 990 km flight with a tailwind and returns, flying into the same wind.The total flying time is 3 hrs 20 mins and the airplanes speed in still air is 600 km/h what is the speed of the wind?

Comment: What have you tried? You must have tried _something_ since you thought to tag the question "quadratics". Please explain that. Where do you get stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the speed of the wind is $x$ km/hr. Then the airplane speeds during upwind and downwind are $600+x$ and $600-x$, respectively. Then 
$$ \frac{990}{600+x} + \frac{990}{600-x} = 3\frac{1}{3}$$

Solve it and you will have $x = 60$ km/hr.